# Docker compose work on linux environment but not windows environment

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using 2 different environments for development: (1) one is a Linux VM at home while (2) another is the windows laptop at office.

The Dockerfile of the angular environment worked fine until a few days ago. Now, it shows the following error when I try to start the docker container with docker-compose on the laptop:

```
ng    | /bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found
ng exited with code 127
```

However, the same issue does not occurs on my Linux VM.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq google-chrome-stable

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json package-lock.json /app/

RUN npm install
#RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  dj:
    container_name: dj
    build: Backend
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
    volumes:
      - ./Backend:/code
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  ng:
    container_name: ng
    build: Frontend/SPort
    volumes:
      - ./Frontend/SPort:/app
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
```

Comment: Nothing you show here mentions `sudo`.  Which component exactly is generating that error?

Comment: That's the weird part. The error just pop up when try to use `docker-compose up`, the ng container show the error immediately and exited with code 127.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to fix the `sh` script in your `Dockerfile`

add this:

```
RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix && dos2unix /path/to/the/script
```

hope that will help since the error comes from `CRLF` characters in windows

Comment: I am sorry but can you please explain more on the code provided? I am not quite sure on the part /path/to/the/script.

Comment: look at the files you copied in `- ./Frontend/SPort:/app` and you `COPY` also in `/app` I think there is some `sh` files there you need to find all the script there and fix them using `dos2unix`

Comment: Nope. The folder `./Frontend/SPort` is the folder of my angular project and there are no `sh` files in it.

Comment: look at this http://sql313.com/index.php/43-main-blogs/maincat-dba/62-using-notepad-to-change-end-of-line-characters

Comment: Don't know why, but I remove all the images and volume created and rebuild the docker image again and it works again. Anyway, the problem is solved by now. Thank you.